# How to executeJavascript and return value on phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

On electronjs i can use executeJavascript on another site and return value like bellow, could i do that on phonegap?

```
mainWindow.webcontent.executeJavasciprt(someScript)
```

i found it, 
using window.open

```
var ref = window.open('your_url_hear', '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', async function() {//wait for url stop loading
    ref.executeScript({code: `document.write('123'); function returnvalue(){
    var value = 123;
    return value
};returnvalue()`},function(value){
    //callback return value of the last row of code, we can use ref.executeScript({file:'patch_to_js_file'}) 
    console.log(value)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to run your code as a string type try below code this works fine

```
win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`alert(${varible_value});`);
```

Comment: Or you can learn from the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554536/electron-webcontents-executejavascript-cannot-execute-script-on-second-on-load

Comment: YUP that forr electron, i know that, but i am looking for any way to do that in phonegap